# How can I remove a class when an animation is over?

Tags: jquery, css, animate.css

I have jQuery codes which is the below;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btn").on("click",function(){
    $(".article_heading").addClass("animated bounce",function(){
        $(".article_heading").removeClass("animated bounce");
    });
 });
});
```

and my problem is with animate.css.and I can't play animate.css more than once because of this problem I want to solve with jquery as you see on the top but when I added animated bounce class it has to be deleted after my animation end. is it imposseble ? I couldn't do that callback and other way could you help me about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the class, you can listen to the `animationend` event and then remove the class and event listener in the callback when `animationend` is fired.

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  $(".article_heading").addClass("animated bounce").on('animationend', function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass("animated bounce").off('animationend');
  });
});
```

You could also use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to attach the event so that it is only fired once (which means that the handler doesn't need to be removed in the callback).

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  $(".article_heading").addClass("animated bounce").one('animationend', function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass("animated bounce");
  });
});
```

Comment: it's awesome the problem has solved thanks to you :))